# Javascript: How to cut a specific part of a string?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

**THE SITUATION:**

I need to cut a specific part of a string.
That part will not always be the same in length and content.

The only thing i know is that it will always start with: `<style>`
and finish with: `</style>`

All the content in the middle must cut out (style tag included).

**THE QUESTION:**

How can i cut a specific part of a string knowing only the begin and the end of that part?

Comment: Are you looking to extract information between the tags, or remove information between the tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try something like this:

```
var str = '<style> p {margin: 0; } </style> other text';
var result = str.replace(/\<style\>.*\<\/style\>/, '');
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/vLme1bps/)

**UPD:** For getting content in tag `style` (style tag included) try this:

```
var result = str.match(/\<style\>.*\<\/style\>/)[0]
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/vLme1bps/4/)

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate DOM directly with javascript without regex or jquery. You need to select the parent element of the target element/class/id and then remove the child.

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {color:blue;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
```

JavaScript:

```
var text = document.querySelectorAll("style")[0];
text.parentNode.removeChild(text);
```

Demo in https://jsfiddle.net/kt6feq92/

Comment: Can you update please the link to the demo. It isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have following `string`

```
var str = '<style>I am a style</style>';
var res = str.replace("<style>", "").replace("</style>", "");
alert(res);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rq486dhh/)**

Answer (score 0):

Get the part string:

```
theString = 'asdfasdf<style>aaaaaaaaaaaaaa</style>bbbbbbbb'
targetString= theString.replace(/<\/style>/ig,'<style>').split('<style>')[1];
```

Delete the whole string:

```
theString = 'asdfasdf<style>aaaaaaaaaaaaaa</style>bbbbbbbb'
targetString= theString.replace(/<style>.*<\/style>/ig,'');
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for a [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

The following regex will select the string that is between `<style></style>` tags:

```
\<style\>(.*)\<\/style\>/s
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aC9zH0/1)